# Why there is such low diversity of higher plants in sea?

Tags: evolution, botany, ecology

I think it could be because of mycorrhiza or maybe because of the problem with flowering and seeds.
But really, I don't know.

edit:
by higher plants I meant Embryophytes

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The concept of higher / more evolved lineages is undefined. You should probably just name what lineage you call "higher plants". Maybe you meant Angiosperm or Embryophytes, ...?